# Chained jquery deferred.then() not returning the proper promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, chaining

I've taken the sample code from the jquery deferred.then() documentation: [Chain tasks.](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#example-3)

**The problem** I found is with the `chained.done` handler that, from what I understand, should be called when all the requests are done. **Instead** the handler is executed when the first request is done, and it retrieves the payload from this same request.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
var request = $.ajax("http://www.json-generator.com/j/bPyGnSXXTm", {
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true
}),
    chained = request.then(function (data) {
        console.log('First call, data:', data);
        $('body').append('<p>' + 'First call, data: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</p>');
        return $.ajax(data[0].url, {
            crossDomain: true
        });
    });

chained.done(function (data) {
    // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
    console.log('Second call, data:', data);
    $('body').append('<p>' + 'Second call, data: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</p>');
});
```

You can find a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ammutable/nGthY/1/).

Furthermore you can open console and see that the handler is being executed before the second request, (Activate log XMLHttpRequests).

From my understanding the `chained` is getting the value of `request`, and not the returned value of the `$.ajax` as it should.

Comment: in your code, chained is still the first call

Comment: @A.Wolff my code replicated the one from jquey documentation, the variable `chained` gets assigned to the request.then function, maybe I don't understand your comment... could you please elaborate a little more? Thank you!

Comment: Ok i see, `then` was buggy before jQuery 1.8.x(?) AFAIK, see, you need to upgrade jQuery to 1.8 or use pipe() instead of then()  pipe: http://jsfiddle.net/nGthY/2/  or jQuery 1.8 http://jsfiddle.net/nGthY/3/

Comment: @A.Wolff you are completely right about that, it works as expected with jquery 1.8.3!

Comment: I'm locked-down on 1.7, so the `pipe` solution you provided works best. @A.Wolff Do you mind to make a answer from your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery prior to 1.8, you need to use `.pipe()` instead of `then()`:

```
chained = request.pipe(function (data) {...});
```

See DOC for change between version: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then